# Stop console updates during multiple long writes

Tags: c#, colors, console

I need to write a long string to the console that uses multiple colors, but I need it to only update visually after all the writes are done. Simply changing the color of the text could be achieved by setting Console.ForegroundColor, but is there any way to "lock" the console, and have it only update once when all writes are complete? One way to achieve this without locking the console would be to use ANSI color codes, but they aren't supported on newer Windows operating systems. What is the best way to only update the console when I've finished my lengthy writes?

Something similar to this:

```
Console.Lock() // Prevents visual updates
// multi_colored_string is StringBuilder
for (int counter = 0; counter < multi_colored_string.Length; counter++)
{
    char next_char = multi_colored_string[counter];
    if (next_char == "a")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
    }
    else if (next_char == "b")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
    }
    Console.Write(next_char);
}
Console.Unlock() // Allows console to update again, reflecting all writes
```

Comment: The console simply doesn't supply this functionality.  You can use your own shell instead that does, and you can (potentially) prevent other threads from writing to standard output while you're doing all of this, but that's all.

Comment: @Servy Own shell? How?

Comment: Store whatever you want to write to the console in a string variable and then pass it to `Console.Write` after you are done.

Comment: That won't work, you can't set different colors for one write.

Comment: @Alireza The same way microsoft wrote *their* own shell, or various linux OSes wrote theirs.  It's actually a fairly common academic problem.  It's almost certainly an unreasonable solution to this problem, as writing a custom shell is *very* involved, but it's a theoretical possibility, unless one is able to find an existing third party shell that has the desired semantics.

Comment: @Servy It's badly tempting for the sake of learning and fun